# HOW can i make dark foreground?

Tags: lighting, black-and-white, background

How can make white background but the person in foreground is dark?

Like this one :

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/aV8NqiYjuIc/mqdefault.jpg

Thanks all

Comment: You might find a lot of information from http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29333/how-can-i-get-a-pure-white-background-in-studio-photography

Comment: This question may be answered by [How do I create silhouettes in a studio environment?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/how-do-i-create-silhouettes-in-a-studio-environment) A.Zayed, does that question cover the same ground? If not, please edit your question to reflect the differences.

Comment: Also see [What setup/gear is needed to get this silhouette low-key effect?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/63673/what-setup-gear-is-needed-to-get-this-silhouette-low-key-effect) and 
[Profile Silhouettes and Rim Lights: How to Do it Right?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/26945/profile-silhouettes-and-rim-lights-how-to-do-it-right)

Answer (score 1):

It is not the foreground that is dark, it is the background that is *brighter* than the subject.

You must simply take a photo with light illuminating the background much more than the subject. There are two ways:

1. Point a light at the background, placing it behind your subject.
2. Place a light behind a translucent background.